# PHP explode() - how to avoid blank lines?

Tags: php, explode

I think this code puts a blank line at the end. If that is true, how to avoid this?

```
$text = explode( "\n", $text );
foreach( $text as $str ) { echo $str; }
```

Comment: Trim the text before you explode it? `$text = trim($text, "\n");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim the text before you explode it.

```
$text = trim($text, "\n");
$text = explode( "\n", $text );
foreach($text as $str) {
    echo $str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First way is to you `trim()` function before exploding the string.

```
$text = trim($text, "\n");
$text = explode( "\n", $text );
foreach( $text as $str ) { echo $str; }
```

Another way could be using `array_filter()` after exploding.

```
$text = explode( "\n", $text );
$text = array_filter($text);
foreach( $text as $str ) { echo $str; }
```

By default `array_filter()` removes elements that are equal to `false`, so there is no need to define a callback as second parameter.

Anyway I think that first way is the best here.

Answer (score 3):

You could, instead of [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php), use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php) with the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`

**Example**:

```
$aLines = preg_split('/\n/', $sText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

But notice that `preg_split` [is slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303235/in-php-which-is-faster-preg-split-or-explode) than `explode`.