# In PHP, which is faster: preg_split or explode?

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

Which is faster when using it to extract keywords in a search query in php:

```
$keyword = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $_GET['search']);
```

or

```
$keyword = explode(' ', $_GET['search']);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Explode is faster, per PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

> Tip If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose faster (albeit simpler) alternatives like explode() or str_split().

Answer (score 13):

In a simple usage `explode()` is than faster, see: [micro-optimization.com/explode-vs-preg_split <sup>(link from web.archive.org)</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323205542/http://micro-optimization.com/explode-vs-preg_split/)

But [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) has the advantage of supporting tabs (`\t`) and spaces with `\s`.

the `\s` metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character.

A whitespace character can be (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

- space character (32 = `0x20`)
- tab character (9 = `0x09`)
- carriage return character (13 = `0x0D`)
- new line character (10 = `0x0A`)
- form feed character (12 = `0x0C`)

In this case you should see the cost and benefit.

A tip, use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#112061) for "delete" empty items in array:

Example:

```
$keyword = explode(' ', $_GET['search']); //or preg_split
print_r($keyword);

$keyword = array_filter($arr, 'empty');
print_r($keyword);
```

**Note:** [RegExp Perfomance](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.performance.php)

Comment: explode can support tabs as well. `explode("\t",$string)`

Comment: @Forien I did not say that `explode()` does not support "tabs", I said that `\s` with `preg_split` supports "space" and "tab" at the same time. :)

Comment: No problem, but I found that sentence misleading :) best answer here anyway imho

Comment: in your example there is explore instead of explode

Comment: "in a simple usage explode() is than faster" - is there *any* usage explode wouldn't be faster?

Comment: @eis I was talking about the need, how it will apply, the function itself will always be faster than anything related to regex, or even own implementations written in PHP. What I meant is that in a simple need with explodes you will get the result, if you need something complex you will need to make things more complicated, like loops from different explodes. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 7):

General rule: if you can do something without regular expressions, do it without them!

if you want to split string by spaces, explode is way faster.

Comment: Tip: `explode()` works with other characters as well

Comment: Yes, I know. But if he wanted for example split by spaces OR tabs OR new lines then it wouldn't be good :)