# preg_split() with strings containing '<'

Tags: php, preg-split

I parsing a license key list in php.
Unfortantly the results are not like expected.
It seems that the problem occurs by the special character '<'.
Would be nice if somebody have an idea of possible solutions.

```
$file_content = '
HM$WN*G&Z58CY8FPUA
F*QZHZGK#&*@*492&T
JJKXP<GZRPKGS7J!EW
P8ZHZ<GCNNR6X=Z7PW
C6HXQFGJ*Y2+#SDZT9
BYYYMEGMQ73G5K#U7F
P>+F=GG7F*U#<RT!6H
B+ZZYTGX&LF6@6XUXU
X&PHNAGN+X><NZYN#9';

$file_array = preg_split("/\n/", $file_content);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($file_array);
```

OUTPUT

```
[0] => 
[1] => HM$WN*G&Z58CY8FPUA
[2] => F*QZHZGK#&*@*492&T
[3] => JJKXP P8ZHZ C6HXQFGJ*Y2+#SDZT9
[6] => BYYYMEGMQ73G5K#U7F
[7] => P>+F=GG7F*U# B+ZZYTGX&LF6@6XUXU
[9] => X&PHNAGN+X>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem, have you checked the source? If you are using a browser to look at the results, the browser probably thinks it is an opening html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your split works as it should be, only thing is that browser converts those symbols to tags and causing that. You can check that by running this (I used [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)):

```
<?php
$file_content = '
HM$WN*G&Z58CY8FPUA
F*QZHZGK#&*@*492&T
JJKXP<GZRPKGS7J!EW
P8ZHZ<GCNNR6X=Z7PW
C6HXQFGJ*Y2+#SDZT9
BYYYMEGMQ73G5K#U7F
P>+F=GG7F*U#<RT!6H
B+ZZYTGX&LF6@6XUXU
X&PHNAGN+X><NZYN#9';

$file_array = preg_split("/\n/", $file_content);

array_map("HTMLescape", $file_array);

function HTMLescape($a) {
    echo "<pre>".htmlentities($a)."</pre>";    
}
```

Output:

```
HM$WN*G&Z58CY8FPUA
F*QZHZGK#&*@*492&T
JJKXP<GZRPKGS7J!EW
P8ZHZ<GCNNR6X=Z7PW
C6HXQFGJ*Y2+#SDZT9
BYYYMEGMQ73G5K#U7F
P>+F=GG7F*U#<RT!6H
B+ZZYTGX&LF6@6XUXU
X&PHNAGN+X><NZYN#9
```

Moreover, for just splitting this line, as @Marcin Orlowski pointed, you can opt for [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) which is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303235/in-php-which-is-faster-preg-split-or-explode).

Comment: thanks i forgot htmlentities. the data is correct in the database. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

There's no benefit from using `preg_split()` in your case. Use

```
$file_array = explode("\n", $file_content);
```

instead, or if the content is being read from file, just do

```
$file_array = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

for the same result.

**EDIT**

> but the result should be look like this

If you mean the output is the same as from your question - yes it is, because it is the correct output. The problem is that you are viewing this in web browser which then may consider `<...` as part of HTML markup. Add `echo '<pre>';` before your `print_r()` to prevent this or run your script in console.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine with some minor modifications:

```
<?php

$file_content = <<<'EOT'
HM$WN*G&Z58CY8FPUA
F*QZHZGK#&*@*492&T
JJKXP<GZRPKGS7J!EW
P8ZHZ<GCNNR6X=Z7PW
C6HXQFGJ*Y2+#SDZT9
BYYYMEGMQ73G5K#U7F
P>+F=GG7F*U#<RT!6H
B+ZZYTGX&LF6@6XUXU
X&PHNAGN+X><NZYN#9
EOT;

$file_array = preg_split("/\n/", $file_content);

print_r($file_array);
```

The obvious output on php cli is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HM$WN*G&Z58CY8FPUA
    [1] => F*QZHZGK#&*@*492&T
    [2] => JJKXP<GZRPKGS7J!EW
    [3] => P8ZHZ<GCNNR6X=Z7PW
    [4] => C6HXQFGJ*Y2+#SDZT9
    [5] => BYYYMEGMQ73G5K#U7F
    [6] => P>+F=GG7F*U#<RT!6H
    [7] => B+ZZYTGX&LF6@6XUXU
    [8] => X&PHNAGN+X><NZYN#9
)
```

Note that to visualize that result in a html displaying browser you have to escape the html specific characters (like `<` and `>`). but that has nothing to do with splitting the input string, what your question is about.

Comment: Though you use heredoc, browsers automatically parse HTML tags

Comment: @Thamilan Sorry, can't follow there. First, that is _not_ `heredoc`, but a `nowdoc` definition I use. Second, that string definition has nothing to do with a browser at all. It defines a string on the server side, no browser is involved.

Comment: Yes but while the text is displayed in browser, it will certainly process open and close tags before printing, however, the OP's concept will work in terminal or in console

Comment: @Thamilan Which is exactly what I wrote in the answer, if you read it.

Comment: Extremely sorry about my mistake. Forgive! Read lately. [Better to remove these conversation as it is of no use for future readers] agree?