# php foreach skip empty path of image

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo images using php, my images are stored in array , so I can't skip empty value, my php code is

```
 $images = 'imgs/001.jpg,imgs/001.gif,imgs/002.png,imgs/003.jpg,imgs/004.jpg,
imgs/005.jpg,imgs/006.png,imgs/007.png,';
    $expl = explode (',', $images);

    foreach ($expl as $path){

        if (!empty($path) || getimagesize($path)!== false){
            $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $data = file_get_contents($path);
            $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

            echo '<img src="'.$base64.'" width="300" height="300">' . '<br>';

            var_dump (getimagesize($path));
        }

    }
```

because of the last comma in my $images I get error

```
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\test\php\images\dataimage-explode1-1.php on line 9
```

I tried :  `if (!empty($path) || getimagesize($path)!== false)`

but seems that not working, I get the same error

Comment: Last array element is empty

Comment: add this: **$images = rtrim($images, ',');**, then explode.

Comment: replace OR to AND in your if ```||``` -> ```&&```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Comment: `!empty($path)` should work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here

```
if (!empty($path) || getimagesize($path)!== false) {
```

When `$path` is empty, php checks second condition `getimagesize($path)`, which gives you a warning, because you check `getimagesize('')`.

So, the correct rule is:

```
if (!empty($path) && getimagesize($path) !== false) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest do this

```
$expl = preg_split('@,@', $images, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This will remove all empty entries automatically

Comment: This is a great solution, but if you can do something without regex, you should - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303235/in-php-which-is-faster-preg-split-or-explode

Answer (score 1):

@u_mulder is right but you should also use `trim($images,',')` to remove unnecessary `,` comma at last

```
$expl = explode (',', trim($images,','));
```

Read about [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [one example](https://eval.in/979591)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to fixing the logic error, you can simplify your condition

```
if ($path && getimagesize($path) !== false) { ...
```

`empty` is overkill as it includes an `isset` check that is not necessary considering `$path` will always set by the foreach loop. If `$path` is an empty string it will evaluate as false.